# What is the runtime-EclipseApplication folder for, and can I delete it safely?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to organise the directory structure of my projects' source code and the eclipse workspace etc.

I found a folder called `runtime-EclipseApplication` in a high level folder outside the directories where I keep my workspace and projects.

What is this folder, when/why is it created and is it safe to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default for the workspace name when you use `Run As > Eclipse Application`.

You can look in the `Eclipse Applications` section of the `Run > Run Configurations` dialog to see what (if anything) is using this workspace. The workspace name is shown in the `Location` field of the `Main` tab.

Comment: Thank you. Nothing came up in the dialog other than Eclipse Application with some default looking settings. I don't know how it got there but I figure it is safe to delete.